# Are there any methods that returns just the decimal after a division? (Python3)

Tags: python, math, division

In python 3, are there any methods that would return just the decimal value after a division?

For example, if I divided 4 by 5 in this method, it would return 8.

Comment: What if you divided 1 by 3? Should it return 3333333333333333 (etc)? Or just 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use floating-point division. e.g.:

```
(11.0 / 5) % 1 = 0.20000000000000018

(1.0 * 11 / 5) % 1 = 0.20000000000000018
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
>>> int(((4.0 / 5.0) % 1) * 10)
8
```

Comment: Add a `% 10` and it actually works for all inputs that fit in the numeric types.

Comment: Unleas said value is negative. Always be careful with modulo ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate it using `int`, for a generic number `a`:

```
int(10*a)%10
```

However, note that this only works for positive numbers!

If you want it to work for negative numbers as well:

```
int(10*a*cmp(a,0))%10*cmp(a,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without floating point operations, right?

```
foo=lambda x,y: (10*(x%y))/y)

# Demo
>>> for i in range(20):
...   print(foo(i,7), i/7.0)
... 
(0, 0.0)
(1, 0.14285714285714285)
(2, 0.2857142857142857)
(4, 0.42857142857142855)
(5, 0.5714285714285714)
(7, 0.7142857142857143)
(8, 0.8571428571428571)
(0, 1.0)
(1, 1.1428571428571428)
(2, 1.2857142857142858)
(4, 1.4285714285714286)
(5, 1.5714285714285714)
(7, 1.7142857142857142)
(8, 1.8571428571428572)
(0, 2.0)
(1, 2.1428571428571428)
(2, 2.2857142857142856)
(4, 2.4285714285714284)
(5, 2.5714285714285716)
(7, 2.7142857142857144)
```